# Excel 2010 Macro: Replace all cells containing number greater than AND smaller than

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a large excel sheet in which I want to replace several number ranges (all within the same range of cells). For example, I want to replace all numbers greater than -5 and smaller than 5 with the number 0. All numbers greater than 5 and smaller than 10 should be replaced with 1, all numbers greater than -10 and smaller than -5 should be replaced with -1, and so forth.

I tried using this formula

```
Sub replace()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("B2:AI40")
        If IsNumeric(rng) < 5 And IsNumeric(rng) > -5 Then
            rng = 0
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

which doesn't quite do the trick as it replace everything with 0. Similarly, [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=93468) solution doesn't do the trick either. How can I modify either formula to suit my needs, or is such a replacement not possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Sub replace()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("B2:AI40")
        If rng.Value < 5 And rng.Value > -5 Then
            rng = 0
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

`IsNumeric` is a boolean function which either returns 0 or 1, that's why every cell was set to 0 before. If you expect non-numeric values in your cells, you might have to use this code:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("B2:AI40")
        If IsNumeric(rng) then
            If rng.Value < 5 And rng.Value > -5 Then
                rng = 0
            End If
        End if
    Next rng
End Sub
```

The whole task gets simpler (and deals also with your the other cases you mentioned) when you use integer division (`\`) by 5:

```
Sub replace()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("B2:AI40")
        If IsNumeric(rng) then
            rng = rng.Value \ 5
        End if
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! It was all numeric values, so it worked with the first solution!

Comment: @DanielHagemeier: see my edit for a simpler solution which also deals with rng>5, rng>10, ...

Comment: @DocBrown: Although this is a small range, `Application.ScreenUpdating  = False` before the code and `Application.ScreenUpdating  = True` after the loop will avoid the flicker.

Comment: nice solution, like it... +1 :)

Comment: + 1 Nice one :) I was waiting for your answer to get selected so I could post my answer. Is it ok if I do so?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: you don't need my permission to post any answers here. But if there is already a good answer for a post here on SO, I typically do only post another one if I think it will bring the OP some new insights.

Comment: I just re-read your comment.... `But if there is already a good answer for a post here on SO, I typically do only post another one if I think it will bring the OP some new insights. ` If that is the case then I will post an answer...

Comment: The fastest way to do this especially if you have so many rows and looping will take huge time, is to just add a new column and put formulas in it then delete the old column.

Answer (score 2):

Please do not select this as an answer.

This post is only to show you a much much faster method than what you are actually using. Technically you are looping through every cell in `B2:AI40`. i.e your code is looping 1326 times (`=34 Cols * 39 Rows`)

Here is a much much faster method using only 17 loops

**Logic:**

1. < 10 And > 5 (In other words 6,7,8,9 to be replaced by 1)
2. < 5 And > -5 (In other words -4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4 to be replaced by 0)
3. < -5 And > -10 (In other words -6,-7,-8,-9 to be replaced by -1)

Now instead of looping ever cell, we will be using `.Replace` to search the above numbers so technically we will **only be looping 17 times as compared to 1326**!

See this sample code

```
Option Explicit

Sub replace()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("B2:AI40")

    With rng
        For i = 6 To 9 '<~~ 4 loops
            .replace What:=i, Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i

        For i = -4 To 4 '<~~ 9 loops ; 7 if when i = 1 or 0 it doesn't do anyting
            If i <> 1 And i <> 0 Then
                .replace What:=i, Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                ReplaceFormat:=False
            End If
        Next i

        For i = -9 To -6 '<~~ 4 loops   
            .replace What:=i, Replacement:="-1", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for showing a completely different apporach, and how to use "Replace" for this kind of problem. However, since Excel has to loop internally, and "Replace" is a complex function, it is not per se clear that this is really more efficient - did you actually measure running times? And this solution is IMHO much less maintainable than mine.

Comment: @DocBrown: Thanks for appreciating it :) Yes this is more efficient. The efficiency can be seen significantly over a much bigger range. Right now it is just 38 rows. Imagine 10000 rows... looping 17 times as compared to 340000 times! :)